# Is there a way in VBA to have the SEARCH function only pick up cells that includes the "exact" text instead of similar text?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get VBA / Excel to label cells as a specific category based on the specific text that the cell contains.

Currently I'm using the following:

'''
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""fee"",RC[-5]))),""fee"","N/A")
'''

For the majority of the cells included in my regular dataset, I am able to categorise cells that contains the text "fee" as "Fee", however, there are cases where the cell could include word like "Coffee" where "fee" is also included.

In that case, these cells will also be categorised as "fee" as well which is not desirable.

Is there a way to avoid this by adding more condition / codes?

Comment: Please try describing **those conditions**.

Comment: Do you want searching for such a **word**? " fee" will return what you need, except if it is the first word in the sentence...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not using `COUNTIF()`

Comment: Also, why do you tag this with 'VBA' when it's about 'Excel-Formula'? Consider changing tags to get the help you are looking for **or** add your vba-code for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the cell starts/ends with *Fee* or if it's equal to fee.

[image]

My formula in column B is:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2;{"fee";"* fee";"fee *"}))>0;"Fee";"Other")
```

Comment: Think the formula separators correspond to some middle European settings, imo the (English) formula should be rather `=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A2,{"fee","* fee","fee *"}))>0,"Fee","Other")`

Answer (score 1):

If the contents is a multi-word string, you need to include delimiters.

In the formula below, I used `space` as the delimiter.  Note that I added a `space` before and after the string being searched, and also used `SUBSTITUTE` to remove any punctuation.  I only removed the `dot`, but, depending on your data, you may need to nest some `SUBSTITUTE` functions to also remove other punctuation (eg comma, exclamatdion points, etc)

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" fee "," " & SUBSTITUTE(G2,".","") & " "))
```

[image]

Comment: Clever adaption of the base string +:) - Side note: Using the new dynamic array features of 2019+/MS365 the input range could be extended even to comprise `G2:G6` thus delivering a compact spill range result.